# Facebook SDK 4.0 AppInvite not getting any notification

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-invite-friends

I am developing an iOS application in which I have to invite Facebook friends,for that I am using Facebook SDK 4.0 new feature using [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios)
link.

I am able to get the friends list and I select a friend and then I click "Send" for sending an invite. Despite of successful invitation sent my friend didn't get any notification on his Facebook account on web.

My app is under development,Is this the issue regarding this?

Friends only get the notifications on mobile app?

Please take a look at the screens provided here.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add iOS iPhone Store Id in app's setting please have a look into attached screenshot. And also fill all to required information for iOS when you are generating **AppUrlLink**

You have to test it with test users if its in development not live.
And yes the invite will only receive to mobile user (in iOS Facebook app).

[image]